# Throw exception for Angular.js expression

Tags: angularjs

Is this possible to configure?

From [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), expressions are forgiving, but I would like to know what my mistake is.

> Forgiving: In JavaScript, trying to evaluate undefined properties generates ReferenceError or TypeError. In Angular, expression evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null.

Comment: You have probably figured that out by now, but I am afraid there is no way to configure that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is,

In Angular, the $interpolate service is responsible for working with binding expression, since this service is forgiving you do not see any errors. However you could create wrapper for it that would notify when possibly falsy result is produced.

The code below is from http://odetocode.com/  [See this blog post](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/27/debugging-angularjs-data-binding.aspx)

```
app.config(function($provide){
    $provide.decorator("$interpolate", function($delegate){

        var interpolateWrap = function(){
            var interpolationFn = $delegate.apply(this, arguments);
            if(interpolationFn) {
                return interpolationFnWrap(interpolationFn, arguments);
            }
        };

        var interpolationFnWrap = function(interpolationFn, interpolationArgs){
            return function(){
                var result = interpolationFn.apply(this, arguments);
                var log = result ? console.log : console.warn;
                log.call(console, "interpolation of  " + interpolationArgs[0].trim(), 
                                  ":", result.trim());
                return result;
            };
        };

        angular.extend(interpolateWrap, $delegate);
        return interpolateWrap;

    });
});
```